# Layout bug in Careers front page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

While browsing careers.stackoverflow.com I notcied this little glitch here:

[image]

This is taken on Chrome Version 40.0.2214.93 m.

Switching to IE11, it does seem to look as intended:

[image]

You must not be logged in, in order to view this page.

/Update: This only occurs on the German and French version of the site. En-us and En-uk are unaffected.

My best guess is, that this occurs, due to the length of the text in German and French, so a line break gets inserted.

A Margin-bottom of 2px would probalby solve this - or changing the text of one of the buttons.

"Kandidaten durchsuchen" could very well be written as "Kandidaten suchen", which would reflect the english translation of Search Candidates instead of "crawl all candidates".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this. We'll get a fix out shortly!

Update: A fix has been rolled out. Thanks again.